# Email address used by website but I do not know where

Tags: email, plugin-contact-form-7, contact

I build a website for a client. This client then filled the website with content. I created 20 contact forms, using the contactform 7 and WP Mail SMTP Pro plugin.
The website has now more than 100 pages.

First my email address was used for the sites admin. I changed this later to my clients email address. I also used the client his email address for all of the contact forms.

But now I still get a emails from the site, every now and again. When a visitor from the site used the site to email my client, either by contactform, or otherwise (I do not know exactly how). Instead of sending the email to my client, the email was send to my email address.

I want to change this, but do not know from what part of the website the emails are coming from. They are not coming from the contact forms, I changed the email addresses there.

Is there a way I can see what page the emails are coming from? The people who send the emails do not remember which part of the website they used when sending the emails.

Maybe there is a way to download all of the source code of the website?

Comment: For the notifications with both CF7 and WPF, you could add a notice at the bottom that tells you which form it's coming from. While you're in there, double check each form.  Also, when you change a site's admin address there is a verification that needs to be processed.  Is it possible that your client didn't complete the verification?

Answer (score 1):

Email settings are usually somewhere in the database. You'll likely find it in a table that gives you a good clue about where the setting can be changed. It may be wise not to just search-and-replace it directly since data can be serialized, meaning that if you replace the address with a different one that has a different number of characters, that breaks the setting. However, there are plugins that can do safe search-and-replace because they unserialize and re-serialize data.

If you don't find the email address anywhere in the database, the other option would be in the files. Yes, you can download the site's files, typically using an FTP client, sometimes using a host's file manager tool. Then you would want to run a "find in files" type command to search for the email address, and again, carefully replace it. If you do find the email address in files, it would be better to take the time to convert that to a setting that can be changed in wp-admin, rather than having to edit any of the theme or plugin files directly.

Comment: Thank you so much. Somebody else mailed through the contactform and remembered where and let me know. So I finally have my answer! Thank you very much for your answer. Always good to know how to go about next time.